# Focusing the drawer in TextMate on Lion

Tags: osx-lion, textmate

In Snow Leopard and before, Ctrl-Tab would toggle keyboard focus between the active editing window and the project drawer, so that you could navigate the project tree with the arrow keys, jump to the top with Alt-Up, etc.

This doesn't work in Lion anymore though, which is cramping my keyboard-based workflow. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by installing the [MissingDrawer plugin](https://github.com/jezdez/textmate-missingdrawer).  It has a different functionality from the original drawer, but allows the `Ctrl-Tab` shortcut to work.